# Find which file failed during data migration from SQL Server to crm dynamics

Tags: c#, ssis, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a problem with my ssis package which I use to migrate data from database to CRM. I created script component for this task, and almost everything is working OK but I have a lot of columns (150+) and unfortunately during export data to CRM I received such issue: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32K6A.png)

Is any way to get information which exactly column/filed is broke? I tried use "try and catch" to see exception:

```js
        Entity new_entity = new Entity("my_entity");
        
            try { if (!Row.abc_IsNull) new_entity["my_abc"] = Row.abc; }
            catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("my_abc"); }
            
            organizationservice.Create(new_entity);
```

but in result I received the same information.